# Make ubuntu 20 look like 17.04

Tags: unity, 20.04

I really like the look and feel of ubuntu before they ditched unity. The last version to use unity was 17.04. The problem is 17.04 ended life in January 13, 2018.

How do I make ubuntu 20.4 (the latest version) look like ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: You can try http://ubuntuunity.org/, which uses Unity (it's **not** GNOME made to look like Unity). However, it is not a officially supported edition of Ubuntu.

Comment: While the duplicate may help and **may** be what OP wants, imo it's not exactly the same question. Look like Unity != Unity. Answer to: I want to use Unity = *Install Unity*. Answer to: Make Ubuntu look like Unity => *Install Unity* **or** *use Unite extension*. I prefer the latter as Gnome is actively maintained and future-safe.